# Error in fiiting glm using MICE package in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, mice

I have a data set which consists of blank values all categorical variables. I have imputed using MICE package in R. I want to fit logistic regression model on the imputed data sets, however when i use pool function i get the following error :**"Error in pool(fit.mi) : Different number of parameters: coef(fit): 20, vcov(fit): 19"**

```
    data <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\kri\\Desktop\\FINAL MODEL DATA(opt).csv',header=T,na.strings=c("",NA))
View(data)
summary(data)
pMiss <- function(x){sum(is.na(x))/length(x)*100}
apply(data,2,pMiss)
apply(data,1,pMiss)
library(mice)
md.pattern(data)
library(VIM)
library(lattice)
aggr_plot <- aggr(data, col=c('navyblue','red'), numbers=TRUE, sortVars=TRUE, labels=names(data), cex.axis=.7, gap=3, ylab=c("Histogram of missing data","Pattern"))
marginplot(data[c(1,17)])
data$ASA <- as.factor(data$ASA)
data$Delirium<- as.factor(data$Delirium)
data$Cardio.related<- as.factor(data$Cardio.related)
data$Diagnosis<- as.factor(data$Diagnosis)
tempData <- mice(data,m=5,maxit=50,meth='polyreg',seed=500)
summary(tempData)
tempData$imp$ASA
tempData$imp$Delirium
tempData$imp$Cardio.related
tempData$imp$Diagnosis
train <- data[1:365,]
test <- data[366:454,]
fit.mi = with(data=tempData, exp = glm(Alos.01. ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train))
combFit = pool(fit.mi)
```